# Is there any way create auto mesh?

Tags: mesh, objects

Is there any way create auto mesh?

In the model I have a wall a snake/caterpillar and a cylinder/wood. I want the snake/caterpillar when its moving forward the rest of the body should get elongated or say, auto mesh to be created and look as if the snake/caterpillar when moving is coming from the wall, and the body is still too long and after a distance, say 10cm ,the body should finish and the tail detaches.

Is there any addon that can create auto mesh or how to animate to feel that the snake/caterpillar is coming from that wall.

[image]

Alternative file attach i want to know the procedure and i want to know how it is made [image]

Comment: (I try to repost this same comment that I posted this morning here... and then... disappeared?) @atek, there is no "auto mesh" feature ora ddona syou intend above, but usin shape keys you can animate the mesh, and get some result useful for that setup, as I understood. See https://www.blender.org/manual/animation/shape_keys/introduction.html

Comment: thanks for replying i have a file hope u go through it and plz tell me how it is build i found this on internet its free to download as what i was thinking i found in that file but i did not get how it is hope u expert can explain me

Comment: sorry, I can't understand how the linked file solves the image above... the "snake" body should keep coming out of the wall, while the whole body also deforms and goes around the cylinder obstacle?